# Values not replaced using .ix in Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a simple function to replace missing values in numerical columns with the average of the non missing values for the columns. The function is syntactically correct and generating correct values. However, the missing values are not getting replaced

Below is the code snippet

```
def fillmissing_with_mean(df1):
    df2 = df1._get_numeric_data()
    for i in range(len(df2.columns)):
        df2[df2.iloc[:,i].isnull()].iloc[:,i]=df2.iloc[:,i].mean()
    return df2

fillmissing_with_mean(df)
```

The data frame which is passed looks like this:

```
age   gender job       name  height
NaN   F      student   alice 165.0
26.0  None   student   john  180.0
NaN   M      student   eric  175.0
58.0  None   manager   paul  NaN
33.0  M      engineer  julie 171.0
34.0  F      scientist peter NaN
```

Comment: df.fillna(df.mean()) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need worry about select the numeric or not , when you doing the mean ,it will only affect to those numeric column, and `fillna` can pass by `pd.Serise`

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
Out[1398]: 
     age gender        job   name  height
0  37.75      F    student  alice  165.00
1  26.00   None    student   john  180.00
2  37.75      M    student   eric  175.00
3  58.00   None    manager   paul  172.75
4  33.00      M   engineer  julie  171.00
5  34.00      F  scientist  peter  172.75
```

More Info

```
df.mean()
Out[1399]: 
age        37.75
height    172.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need. `skipna=True` by default, but I've included it here explicitly so you know what it's doing.

```
for col in ['age', 'height']:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(skipna=True))

#      age gender        job   name  height
# 0  37.75      F    student  alice  165.00
# 1  26.00   None    student   john  180.00
# 2  37.75      M    student   eric  175.00
# 3  58.00   None    manager   paul  172.75
# 4  33.00      M   engineer  julie  171.00
# 5  34.00      F  scientist  peter  172.75
```